# Which way is the fastest to `dd` to the last 512 kilobytes of disk

Tags: unix, dd

I have a 512G disk and I want to clear the last 512k bytes at the end of the disk.

I usually clear it by `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/da0`  the whole disk.

Which way is the fastest to do this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already pointed out, `dd` accepts the `seek=BLOCKS` parameter, which skips `BLOCKS` blocks in the output file.

Now you need to know the exact size of the disk, if you want to write the **last 512kB**. On linux, you can use the `blockdev --getsz DEVICE` command to get the size, in units of **512B**.

So the command-line becomes something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=$YOUR_DEV bs=512 seek=$(( $(blockdev --getsz $YOUR_DEV) - 1 )) count=1
```

Comment: This accepted (?) answer blanks the last 512 bytes of the file while the question was about 512 kilobytes, which is quite larger. The command should be: `dd if=/dev/zero of=$YOUR_DEV bs=512 seek=$(( $(blockdev --getsz $YOUR_DEV) - 1024 )) count=1024`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `seek` predicate to go to the end of the disk.